# Haskell REST/GDATA API library

Tags: api, rest, haskell, gdata

Is there available REST api library for haskell?

I need it primary for google gdata client, but will probably use it for other purposes too.

I know there is HTTP library, but I need something more high level, which supports things like json encoding/decoding, etc...

Comment: There is still a need for a library like this. If anyone wants to write one, I am comfortable brewing up a solution with a partner. Drop a line at alex@hirzel.us .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to "cabal list", there is no such thing among libraries on Hackage. Sad, but true.

Answer (score 2):

Now in 2013 there is the [handa-gdata](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/handa-gdata) package on Hackage.